# Turning a duplicate selection into an update

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates, updates

I've managed to select the count and IDs of each record that has duplicates via:

```
select T1.ID,T2.Count
from MyTable T1
join (SELECT ID,Count(*) as Count FROM MyTable 
where Field_C=X 
and Field_S=Y  
group by NumberField,NameField having count(*)>1) T2 
on T1.NumberField=T2.NumberField
and T1.NameField = T2.NameField
```

This returns the ID of the records I want to update (`T1.ID`) and the value I want to update a CountField with (`T2.Count`).

Just unsure how to change into update after getting this far.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. (At 461, you should kind of know this already)

Comment: if you just want to update T1.ID = T2.Count you can easily convert the sql you have into an update statement.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Actually I am trying to update Record T1.ID Count field with T2.Count. So far this seems to work, might need to make one mod to accomodate my specific situation `Update MyTable T1
join (SELECT ID,Count(*) as Count FROM MyTable 
where Field_C=X 
and Field_S=Y  
group by NumberField,NameField having count(*)>1) T2 
on T1.NumberField=T2.NumberField and T1.NameField = T2.NameField set T1.Count=T2.Count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the select you have already the update  this way

```
    UPDATE MyTable T1
    join (SELECT ID,Count(*) as Count FROM MyTable 
    SET T1.ID = T2.Count
    where Field_C=X 
    and Field_S=Y  
    group by NumberField,NameField having count(*)>1) T2 
    on T1.NumberField=T2.NumberField
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess a long day at the office but this solved it pretty easily. I think having the first select threw me off until I realized I needed to get rid of it entirely as I was not selecting but updating:

```
Update MyTable T1
join (SELECT ID,Count(*) as Count FROM MyTable 
where Field_C=X 
and Field_S=Y  
group by NumberField,NameField having count(*)>1) T2 
on T1.NumberField=T2.NumberField
and T1.NameField = T2.NameField
Set T1.CountField=T2.Count
```